# Pattern for monitoring online offline status of users for display purposes

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, react-native

Is there a common pattern for monitoring online/offline users?

I have a list of users on an app and want to show which ones are online and which ones are offline.

Should I continuously poll an endpoint to check for online status or should I use websockets?

Backend is NodeJS and app is a javascript, react-native application.

Just looking for some direction really!

[image: User list showing online/offline users]

Answer (score 0):

Websockets is probably the fastest way.

Each client has a connected: property and when a client disconnects, you set it to false and emit update.

Edit:  For the client side of things, you can switch on received updates from server like this:

```
switch(action.type) {

   case 'playerDisconnected' :
        updateOnline(action.playerID);
```

The server sends an object with property type and whatever other data.

Comment: Could you provide more detail - should each user component be alerted - can you recommend a good method for doing this?

Comment: @Christ I have updated my answer.  If each user component should be alerted is up to you.  Is it important to have it right away?  Or can you just get new list of online people when you need it?

Comment: Ideally it would be live update, so websockets would be good.

I'm thinking each user is a component which creates a websocket connection to the server.

Is it best practice to update all components when the server says a user is offline?

Comment: Yes, you can emit an update with action type 'playerDisconnected'  and playerID: {playerID}  to everyone connected to the server.   On client side, the player would be removed, as shown in example code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Socket.io** is better way to do this thing. create your custom event online_user and offline_user. Fire the corresponding event from the client side and trigger the call back function on the server side to update the user current status. This way it will be optimized way to handle the user status.